# is the invalidate() function of View class a blocking function? [or, does the logcat show log messages out of order?]

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

In this code,

```
Log.d("MYLOG", "i_confirm in Activity BEFORE = "+Integer.toString(i_confirm)); // LINE 1
theGraph.invalidate();
i_confirm = theGraph.ret_i_confirm(); // LINE 2
```

the logcat shows the outputs due to the functions in line 1 and line 2 before showing me another logcat message that was inside the `onDraw()` function in `theGraph`, which extends `View` class. The above code is in my MainActivity class, inside a function that gets executed when a command button is pressed.

Is `invalidate()` a non blocking method? Does `onDraw()` and everything else inside `invalidate()` get called alongside the execution of the main program? Or is it possible for the logcat to show log messages out of order?

Comment: invalidate is not blocking. it schedules view's onDraw and "onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Blocking methods are those which blocks the current executing thread from further operation until function returns. So as you view can be complex or `may take alot of time to redraw or update` when you call invalidate, so in Android OS View.invalidate tells the system to redraw (via onDraw) the view as soon as `the main thread goes idle`. That is, calling invalidate schedules your view to be redrawn after all other immediate work has finished.

Hope this helps

Comment: so it means onDraw() does not even get called until everything in the Main thread has completed?

Comment: I'm sorry bit I din't understand. So onDraw() gets called after the main thread goes idle. How does that make it a blocking method?

Comment: or in short, in the above code, line 1 and line 2 o get executed first before onDraw() get's called. So is this true?

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I still do not think invalidate() is a blocking method